# Android DDMS 'start method profiling' button disabled

Tags: android, ddms

I am new to Android, and am trying to use the DDMS method profiling. However, the "start method profiling" button in the DDMS UI is disabled. I have my device selected in the device tab and verified that the build variant is debug. What could I be missing?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select your process in the "Devices" list, not just the device. Did you expand the processes list under your device and select your package name?